# Range in message box..?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, evaluate

One more question -> i want to show the range content in an message box, how can i do it?

Let’s say there are new portfolios:1) ABC, 2)XYZ, 3)GHI in an range....when i use below code i am getting no. of portfolios as 3 but i actually want the names of them

MsgBox "New Portfolios found : " & vbNewLine & Sheets("Macro").Range("T2:T25").Row

Comment: Or can i use this................?                                                  Range("S2").Select
Selection.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--ISERROR(O:O))"

If Evaluate("S2").Select > 0 Then

    Range("$A:$Q").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    Range("D1").Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
    Exit Sub

End If

Comment: take that comment and edit your question with it.  Add it on as an update.  reading code in comments is a royal pain in the butt!

Comment: Your code assumes that `ISERROR()` is _only_ counting `#N/A` errors. If you're only interested in those then use `ISNA()` instead.

Comment: @MacroMan so if the `ISERROR()` is only counting `#N/A` why switch to `ISNA()` since `ISERROR()` is already doing that?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ForwardEd `ISERROR` will catch _any_ errors - so if there is a `#DIV/0` error for example then the code in the `If` block will still run, but nothing will return on the filtered data. It's just a bit of a 'sledgehammer' approach

Comment: @MacroMan I was not aware of what would happen with the filtered data.   I thought IFERROR caught most if not all errors, so your previous statement had me a little confused.  Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: ISNA() worked..thanks a lot!!.....one more question -> i want to show the range content in an message box, how can i do it?

Comment: Lets say there are new portfolios:1) ABC, 2)XYZ, 3)GHI in an range....when i use below code i am getting no. of portfolios as 3 but i actually want the names of them

Comment: MsgBox "New Portfolios found : " & vbNewLine & Sheets("Macro").Range("T2:T25").Row